# MySQL query to SQLite query

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I'm trying to convert this MySQL query to an SQLite query...

```
SELECT nickname 
FROM   userinfo 
ORDER  BY Round(RIGHT(nickname, Length(nickname) - Length('string')))
```

...for sorting alphanumeric values. It works as expected in MySQL, but this same query doesn't return any records when I run it on SQLite. How to convert this query to SQLite?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT nickname 
FROM   userinfo 
ORDER  BY Round(RIGHT(nickname, Len(nickname) - Len('string')))
```